# How to obtain the share of observations in a dataset in R?

Tags: r, sum, share

I am new to r and I have run into a problem. I am analysing a dataframe and the question I am working on had three possible answers. I now want to obtain the share per answer in my dataframe. This is my code so far:

```
BES%>%
  group_by(y08) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

and it yields

```
 y08 count
                   <dbl+lbl> <int>
1 1 [Yes: trade union]         261
2 2 [Yes: staff association]    25
3 3 [No]                      1908
```

How can I obtain the absolute number of observations (sum of my integers) and based on that the share of each option? I'd like to create a stratified sample based on this.

(for the srs sample:

```
str_samp <-
  BES%>%
  mutate(strata = sample_size * share) %>%
  group_by(y08) %>%
  sample_n(strata) %>%
  ungroup()
```

this is my code atm. Sample size is defined but I struggle w/ defining the share variable.)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since your question got closed, please edit it with the respective demanded information (see the link I provided). Then we can reopen the question. Unless the linked question above already answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the share/proportions just do this:

```
BES%>%
  group_by(y08) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(share = count/sum(count))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I have tried to add this to my stratified sampling code but it always yields an error saying the sample size must be 3 or less. I get this bcs I only have three strata, but I am looking to draw random samples within these strata. What am I doing wrong here?

```BES%>%                                      
group_by(y08) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
mutate(share = count/sum(count),
unitss = round(share * sample_size)) %>%
sample_n(unitss) %>%
ungroup()
```

Comment: Please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Otherwise it‘s hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
BES %>% count(y08) %>% mutate(share=n/sum(n))
```